# How to import a TypeScript file from another directory?

Tags: requirejs, typescript

This code works fine:

```
import modal = require('./modal');//modal path
class index{
constructor(){
  var_modal = new modal();

 }
}
export = index
```

If I change the require path to `"../../widgets/personInfo/viewmodel"`, after I rebuild the solution Visual Studio gives the error:

> Unable to resolve external module "../../widgets/personInfo/viewmodel", Build: Module cannot be aliased to a non-module type, Invalid 'new' expression

Comment: I found the problem. This is uppercase folder name.
import modal = require('../../Widgets/PersonInfo/viewmodel')

Comment: This might make things easier : https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts/tree/master/test/index#usage

Comment: It is okay to put your comment as an answer and mark this question an answered.

Comment: Applied "steal comment answer" principle here, as described in http://meta.serverfault.com/a/1931

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was found. Folder name was starting with uppercase, while require path was all-lowercase.

Valid code:

```
import modal = require('../../Widgets/PersonInfo/viewmodel')
```